# Python: transpose a list of 100 words of 10 characters

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 100 words, each of exactly 10 characters each. I would like to transpose (if you will) to make a list of 10 words, each with 100 characters. The words don't mean anything, but I am looking for such a functionality. I could do using 2 loops, but I am wondering if there's an easier way like MATLAB's transpose.

Below is a MATLAB example:

```
>> words =
    'KWDSEHQGUI'
    'RSNKYDVCME'
    'MBUSWHEZRI'
    'CVNHWGOQUL'
    'RNTCQWHJKA'

>> wordsT = words'

    'KRMCR'
    'WSBVN'
    'DNUNT'
    'SKSHC'
    'EYWWQ'
    'HDHGW'
    'QVEOH'
    'GCZQJ'
    'UMRUK'
    'IEILA'
```

Solved (thanks to multiple answers below)

```
trans = list(zip(*words))
#To join all the tuples to a string
tWords = []
for items in trans:
    tWords.append(''.join(items))
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @drum added example above.

Comment: `trans = list(zip(*words))` --> `[''.join(thing) for thing in zip(*words)]`

Comment: It's great that you solved it, but you should consider accepting one of the answers, or removing the question, instead of leaving it open and unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight modification in @wwii's comment:

`trans = list(''.join(w) for w in zip(*words))`

Answer (score 1):

As @wwii suggested in a comment, `trans = list(zip(*words))` is very close, but gets you tuples instead of strings.

This works:

```
words = [
    'KWDSEHQGUI',
    'RSNKYDVCME',
    'MBUSWHEZRI',
    'CVNHWGOQUL',
    'RNTCQWHJKA']

trans = list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x),zip(*words)))

print(trans)
```

I found I liked @yabishek's answer better stylistically, but wondered which solution would be faster.

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import randint

size = 100
data = []
for _ in range(size):
    data.append(''.join([chr(65+randint(0, 25)) for _ in range(size)]))


def test_map():
    return list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(*data)))


def test_comprehension():
    return list(''.join(w) for w in zip(*data))


print('map:', timeit(lambda: test_map(), number=10000))
print('comprehension:', timeit(lambda: test_comprehension(), number=10000))
```

Results:

```
map: 1.54815
comprehension: 1.5759290999999997
```

So, as often, `map` is faster than the comprehension, but not by a lot. If you only do this a few times, I'd go with their answer, if you need to do this a lot, or to large amounts of data, I'd go with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single loop itself using join. Sample code example (here w_list is your source list) :

```
transpose_list = []
for i in range(10): 
   transpose_list.append(''.join(w_list[i:i+10]))
print(transpose_list)
```

Above code is as per the specific case where we want to join 10 words from the list and list contains 100 words. You can modify as per the need but the main usage is of join.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = ''.join(initial_list)

final_list = [ str[i:i+10] for i in range(0,len(str),10)]
```